# Bootstrap-vue Modal: How to load iframe only once (not reloading) when opening/closing it

Tags: iframe, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I'm using [**bootstrap-vue Modal**](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal).
I have an **iframe in the modal**.
I would **like to load the iframe only once** (when I first open the modal).
So I can show/hide the modal, while **keeping the iframe state**.
Because I want to use a website containing a **form** as the iframe URL and **want to keep the user's input**.
It's working fine on a standalone bootstrap modal, but I cannot get it to work with bootstrap-vue Modal.
Any idea on how to achieve this?

```
<b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>Show</b-button>

<b-modal id="modal-1">
 <iframe src="https://example.com" onload="alert('Loaded');"></iframe>
</b-modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<b-modal>` is `lazy` by default.
Meaning their content is only rendered when the modal is opened.

If you don't want this behavior, you can add the `static` prop to `<b-modal>`, which will render the modal `in-place`, and turn off the lazy behavior.

[Docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#lazy-loading-and-static-modals)

Comment: Thank you @Hiws, with this settings the iframe loads before the modal is opened, but the iframe still reloads when opening/closing the modal :/ : `<b-modal id="modal-1" :static="true" :lazy="false"><iframe src="https://example.com" onload="alert('Loaded');"></iframe></b-modal>`, any idea on how to tackle the issue? Cheers

Comment: Interesting, looks like when the modal opens and closes, it causes a re-render of the content, which then makes the iframe reload itself. Based on that, i would say there isn't any way for you to do what you want while using `<b-modal>`

Comment: Thank you very much @Hiws, I ended up using the native Bootstrap modal which doesn't reload the iframe :)